Is there a WAY to view unit TEST COVERAGE in Visual Studio Professional 2022?
I'm looking for a tool to view unit test coverage in Visual Studio. I've seen that there are extensions like "Fine Code Coverage" or "dotCover". But I have problems to install them.
When I tried to install "Fine Code" I had the following problem when opening the extension window.

Was anyone able to put some of these tools into operation?
When I tried to install "Fine Code Coverage"
Thank you!! :)

I recommend you "SonarQube" and here u have integration instructions: https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarlint/visual-studio/getting-started/installation/

But SonarQube is for quality software, no test-coverage

Yes it does: https://docs.sonarsource.com/sonarqube/9.8/analyzing-source-code/test-coverage/dotnet-test-coverage/
